# How to update associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bill_items
  has_many :items, through :bill_items

  def add(item)
    BillItem.create(bill: self, item: item)
    update_total
  end

  def update_total
    total = 0
    bill_items.each do |item|
      total += item.price
    end
    self.update(total: total)
  end
end

class BillItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bill
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bill_items
end
```

I'm trying to update all billitems attached to a bill by doing the following:
`bill.bill_items.update_all(price: new_price)`

This seems to update the actual record but not the associated record. ie. If I run `BillItem.pluck(:price)` I'll get the new prices, but if I run `bill.bill_items.pluck(:price)` I'll get the old ones. How do I update the associated records as well?

Comment: this is because of your **bill** object is not reloaded in memory while it updated database , so you need to reload the object or fetch that object again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [reload](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) method. It reloads the record from the database.

```
bill.bill_items.update_all(price: new_price)
bill.reload
```

Comment: Thanks that did it- why is that necessary? I just assumed that if the record itself is updated then it would update the associated records?

Comment: @DavidM ActiveRecord caches associations. Records are old because they come from cache.